# $timeout is behaving differently

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, timeout

Here is the code im using.Im trying to display the html elements which comes under this directive tags to display after 4 secs. When the page is loading for the first time it delays the html elements as specified, but when i navigate to another page and come back to the same the delayed elements are instantly displayed

```
   Utils.directive('ieUtilsError', function() {
     var directive = {};
     directive.link = function(scope, element, attrs) {
     element.attr("style","display:none") 

      function show() {
      element.attr("style","display:inline")
    }

      $timeout(function() {
      show();
    }, 4000);
  }
});
```

Comment: Please verify, whether the directive initiated two times. This may do the trick. When you come back to the same page, the second time initiated timeout will be triggered.

Comment: can please tel me how to do that as im a newbie!

Comment: Put a **breakpoint** on that **$timeout** function, click on **another page**, and **redirect back to the earlier page**, and see if the debugger brings you to the breakpoint, if it does, it means each time you enter that page, timeout function is being run

Answer (score 0):

That's page is not reloaded when you press back button it will keep the old page that's why your timeout is now working.

better use route when navigating through web pages, it will help you to reload the page if you press back button.

```
function myController($route, $rootScope)
{ $rootScope.$on('$rou‌​teUpdate', function() { if (/*shouldReload*/) { 
$route.reload(); } } }
```

Comment: ya i tried using that and its resulting in performance issue. My dashboard takes lot of time to load if i add that to the routes any idea how deal with the performance thing

Comment: in that case you need to optimize you code to maximum extent. I don't think that's the problem with the routes.